# Batch variable command input

Tags: batch-file, command, netsh

I am trying to make a program that names and puts a password for a hotspot. I will have a choice to name my hotspot and put a password.
Please help if your understand.

```
@echo off
Title KEVINS HOTSPOT UPLINK
mode 100, 25
```

//HERE MY PROBLEM STARTS

```
echo Name your hotspot
set/p "ssid=>%name%"
echo Put a password for your hotspot:
set/p "key=>%key%"
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%name% key=%key%
goto choice
```

//REST OF CODE BELOW

```
:choice
echo Hotspot Uplink
set/p "do=>"
if %do%==Start goto start
if %do%==start goto start
if %do%==Stop goto stop
if %do%==stop goto stop
if %do%==End goto end
if %do%==end goto end
goto choice

:start
cls
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
goto choice

:stop
cls
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
goto choice

:end
cls
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
echo Thank you for using Kevin's Hotspot Uplink!
pause
```

Comment: Can you please specify what the problem is? What's expected to happen, what actually happens? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Ok, what i would like the code to do is allow the user to name a hotsted network, and put their own password. Thats what i tried to do with the variables %name% and %key%. When i test the code, the hostednetwork gets the name =key(and the name you set).

Answer (score 1):

```dos
set /p "varName=prompt text to show to user"
```

So, it should be something like

```dos
set /p "ssid=Name your hotspot: "
set /p "key=Put a password for your hotspot: "
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%ssid% key=%key%
```

Of course you should check that the user typed something (ex.)

```dos
set "ssid="
set /p "ssid=Name your hotspot: "
if not defined ssid goto :eof
```

And also, if the user inputs an empty string, your `if` commands will fail. Include a check for the empty value or quote the strings being compared

```dos
:choice
    echo Hotspot Uplink
    set "do="
    set /p "do=>"
    if /i "%do%"=="start" goto start
    if /i "%do%"=="stop"  goto stop
    if /i "%do%"=="end"   goto end
    goto :choice
```